# ASP button to open new window to SSRS report with parameter

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, reporting-services

I'm building a page that is a simple ASP.NET form with C# codebehind. I need a button (or some kind of control) that will open a link to a new window, and I have found code that will do that using Javascript, and I have found code I can use to make my button open my SSRS report with a parameter passed from my aspx page dynamically. I have not found anything to handle both.

My asp form starts with a simple text box looking for an NPI (type of ID). That NPI is used for searching a database and populating a form. I also want to have a button on the page that will grab the NPI entered by the user and pass that to a new window opening my SSRS report.

I've researched this and I know I can use Javascript to open a new window, which would be great, but I don't know how to include the user input NPI into the JS version. I know that I can't use the codebehind to open a new window, but I can use Response.Redirect to send the NPI to the URL for the SSRS report. I can't find the combination of the two.

Thank you in advance. This is my first time posting on StackOverflow, though it use it daily for answers. I apologize for any screw-ups I'm making.

The TextBox:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="NPI" runat="server" Width="144px"></asp:TextBox>
```

The button that opens my SSRS report currently:

```
<asp:Button ID="reports" runat="server" Text="View Reports" 
    onclick="reports_Click" />
```

Here is the codebehind for the button:

```
protected void reports_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)  
{  
    Response.Redirect("http://myReportServer/Pages/ReportViewer.aspx?%2fDRPreports%2fApplicantOverview&rs:Command=Render&npi=" + HttpUtility.UrlEncode(NPI.Text));  
}
```

Comment: I have the solution to this, and I'm going to post it as the answer once enough time has passed for me to answer my own question. It's really very simple.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's try this to open the report in a new window. The ASPX:

```xml
<asp:TextBox ID="txt" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:Button  ID="take" runat="server" onclick="take_Click" Text="no"/>
```

The ASPX.cs code behind:

```
Response.Write("<script>window.open('../About.aspx?qs=" + txt.Text + "','_blank');</script>");
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I like how concise that is.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to find the answer after reading through a number of sites that had similar, though not exact, issues. I didn't see the answer on StackOverflow so instead of deleting my question I thought I would provide a solution in case it may ever be helpful.

The solution is painfully simple. As mentioned in the original post, for a new window, the codebehind can't be used. Only use that if you're okay with the user leaving the page. For a new window, change the button code to:

```
<asp:Button ID="reports" runat="server" Text="View Reports" 
    onclientclick="Navigate()" />
```

The onclientclick now references the JS needed to open a new window. That script is:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function Navigate() {
        var w = document.getElementById('NPI').value
        window.open('http://MyReportServer/Pages/ReportViewer.aspx?%2fDRPreports%2fApplicantOverview&rs:Command=Render&npi=' + w);
    }
</script>
```

As you can see, it's nothing more than creating the variable (w) and assigning the value of the NPI text box to it. Then, in the window.open, tack the variable W to the end as shown.

Now it will open the SSRS report with the NPI parameter assigned when it loads. If this is too simplistic, I can remove the entire post. Otherwise, I hope someone else finds it helpful to have both options (the response.redirect and the JS open.window) in one posting.